# Objective-C: Name of the method that adjust floating point value to 0-1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, naming-conventions, method-names

I created the following method to use rate safely.
(Sometimes rate can become invalid value like INFINITY, NAN, or out of 0-1)

```
-(double)XXXX:(double)rate
    if (rate >= 1) {
         return 1;
    } else if (rate <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (0 <= rate && rate <= 1) {
        return rate;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What should I name this method?

**EDIT:**
I use rate to display progress of time with UISlider, UIProgress, or just NString(XX %).

Usage of the method are:

```
rate = [objectOrClass XXXX: currentTime / totalTime];
rate = [objectOrClass XXXX:(currentTime + additionalTime) / totalTime];
```

I also use it to calculate currentTime from rate:

```
currentTime = [objectOrClass XXXX:rate] * totalTime;
```

Comment: I'm new to objective-c. So I'm not good at naming rules of it yet.

Comment: Same name as you would in other languages - what would the user who specified this algorithm call it?

Comment: - (double)returnRate:(double)rate

Comment: @Mark In other language, method name is `verb+Noun`. But in objective-c, method name is `noun` without `verb` like `stringWithFormat` or `imageNamed`.

So `-(double)rate:(double)rate` is good name for objective-c?

Comment: ratio is not what the user calls this - a ratio is in effect one number dived by another - also in any language ratio is a bad name as ratio of what?

Comment: pushViewController: has a verb :) name the method the way you will easily remember it.

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted for close. I for one like to follow the naming conventions of the language I use, and I don't find it subjective in any way. ObjC has a convention for naming these methods, as already pointed out.

Comment: @Krumelur I agree with you. I feel that more people want to close questions because they don't like the questions these days than a year ago.

Comment: We can write any name as method name that is our convenience and understanding purpose.

Comment: @js_: How and where did you call -(double)XXXX:(double)rate method?

Comment: @PrasadG thanks. I'd like to follow the objective-c's rule to write code. 
I added usage of the method to the question.

Comment: This would probably fit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ better

Comment: @JamesWebster thanks for good advice. i think so, too. i'll post questions there next time i want to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(double) adjustRate:(double)rate;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static inline float RateAligned(float rate) {
    return MAX(.0f, MIN(1.0f, rate));
}
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't know `static inline`. I tested the function and it works. I like short code. But `MAX(.0f, NAN) returns 0.0` but `MAX(NAN, .0f) returns NAN`. Is it safe to assume that `MAX(.0f, NAN) returns 0.0`. Or is it implementation-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

```
When totalTime is zero  you will get INFINITY.

When totalTime and currentTime both are zeros you will get NAN.

When (currentTime + additionalTime) and currentTime both are zeros you will get NAN.
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question..